# Shell script to find OSX version

Tags: macos, shell, version

I tried sw_vers but it only prints the information to the terminal. I cannot use it, as I have to store it in a variable and then compare.

Based on version I have to move files to appropriate location in file system.

What's the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Any command that outputs information to a terminal can be used to get that same information into a variable, by setting the variable equal to the command enclosed within back ticks. `VAR=\`ls\`` runs the `ls` command and assigns `VAR` to the output of it.

Comment: @mah:thanks for letting me know.I am not a developer who is familiar with the scripting languages,I do development using objective-c.So I wasn't aware of that. Thank you very much again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way to do it:

```
v=$(sw_vers -productVersion)

echo $v
10.9.3
```